# How to update: (COCOA/OSX) ABPerson / ABMultiValue (phonenumbers)?

Tags: cocoa, macos, addressbook, abaddressbook, abmultivalue

II trying to change the value of ABPerson / ABMultiValue (the phone numbers).

Anyway to update these?

```
ABAddressBook *ab = [ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook];  
NSArray *persons = [ab people];

int j=[persons count];

for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {
    ABPerson *person = [persons objectAtIndex:i];               
    ABMultiValue *phonenumbers = [person valueForProperty:kABPhoneProperty];
    //  update here *phonenumbers
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling:

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, value, label, null);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, NULL);
```

Add one of these: `ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, value, label, null)` for every value you want to add.

Comment: Instead of `ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty)`, use `ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType)`, otherwise you'll get "Can't return type callbacks for 3" printed on the console (and presumably bad things happening later). [source](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/23289-abnewpersonviewcontroller-crashes-when-scrolling.html)